# Window manager won't start after upgrade to Trusty

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login, window-manager

I recently upgraded my desktop from 13.04 to 14.04. I see the normal graphical login screen, and I'm able to enter my username and password. However, after entering my login information, nothing seems to happen. The login screen disappears, showing just my desktop background. I still have a cursor, but right-clicking and left-clicking don't do anything. Switching to a virtual terminal and killing X gets me back to to the login screen.

I've tried every window manager option listed, and all give the exact same results.

How can I debug or fix this issue?

Comment: maybe possible duplicate of [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) ?